# How do I cross-reference custom labels in my enumitem lists without having the punctuation show up?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am using `enumitem` to handle my enumerate and itemize lists. I have a list like

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic{enumi}.]
\item step the first \label{en:step-1}
\item el secundo \label{en:step-2}
\item item the third \label{en:step-3}
\end{enumerate}
```

When I cross-reference one of these items, the punctuation shows up in the document. For example,

```
Let us reference \ref{en:step-1}.
```

gives me

```
Let us reference Step1..
```

The regular enumerate or itemize environments don't have this problem; punctuation does not show up when cross-referencing.

In the `enumitem` documentation there is an option `afterlabel` but that is only for inline lists.

Is there an option in `enumitem`, or a way of using `enumitem` that adds the correct punctuation to the list, but lets me cross-reference the label without the punctuation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `ref` key:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}]
\item step the first \label{en:step-1}
\item el secundo \label{en:step-2}
\item item the third \label{en:step-3}
\end{enumerate}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}]
\item step the first \label{en:step-1}
\item el secundo \label{en:step-2}
\item item the third \label{en:step-3}
\end{enumerate}
Let us reference \ref{en:step-1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]