# How to remove right parenthesis?

Tags: enumerate, itemize

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Problem One\label{one}. 
\end{enumerate}
See \ref{one}. Problem.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

But that I want

[image]

That is the right parenthesis removed. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: `enumitem` has a `ref` key to format the `\ref` output: `\setenumerate[1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*)}, ref=\textbf{\arabic*}}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56719/35864

Comment: @moewe, It's working.

Comment: Great! I guess we can close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56719/35864. Would you agree?

Comment: @moewe, I agree, too.